# Reverse DNS Lookup Not Functioning Properly

Tags: 18.04, server, dns, postfix, bind

I recently set up a server running Ubuntu 18.04 Server on my local network in a DMZ. I am trying to run it as a mail server, among other things. I had been running a mail server on a desktop PC on the same local network. When I try to send mail from the server, my ISP's servers still use my desktop's machine name ("desktop01") when they try to send mail, not my server's machine name ("server01"). Reverse lookup on the server's name evidently fails (I am hosting my DNS records on GoDaddy), and, since my ISP's servers get a conflict between the name they are/had been using (desktop01) and the name of the machine now attempting to send the email (server01), they do not send/propagate the email.

I called GoDaddy, and they said they no longer support reverse lookup/"glue" records, and I would essentially have to run bind9 to get the reverse lookup on my server's machine name from my outside NAT IP address to work. So, I installed bind9 on the server and think I have it functioning properly, but the reverse lookup still doesn't work and I still can't send email.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be careful running an external DNS. I wouldn't do it myself, and I have been running bind as an internal DNS for years and years.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding! I understand your concerns, but I appear to have no other way of sending email from my spiffy new server. If there's another way to get my ISP to propagate my server's emails without running bind9, that would be great